# Interesting things of ! operation in bool value

Tags: c++

Following are one code snippet

```
#define T 0xFF
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    char c = T;
    bool *pc = (bool *)(&c);
    bool nc = !(*pc);
    cout << "print: " << hex << nc << endl;

    nc = T;
    cout << "print: " << hex << nc << endl;

    nc = c;
    cout << "print: " << hex << nc << endl;
}
```

The results is

```
print: fe
print: 1
print: 1
```

If type cast a char to a bool using the value 0xFF, bool value is 1.

But when type cast a char pointer to a bool pointer, 0xFF becoming 0xFE, only the last bit was flipped by ! operation.

Seems that gcc assumes a bool to be either 0 or 1 and if constructor of bool object is not called, it will just interpret the memory to contain a bool and flip the least significant bit.

But when bool is set by a char, does it trigger the copy contructor? But why different?

Comment: @Charles Thanks for fix the messy code output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `bool` can only take the values `true` and `false`.

When you perform `!(*pc)` you are getting *undefined behavior* because you telling the compiler to perform `!` on a `bool` object when in actual fact `pc` is pointing at a `char` object. (It is the C style cast from `char*` to `bool*` that is dangerous, even though the *undefined behavior* only occurs when you apply the `!` operator.)

When you convert a `char` or an `int` (e.g. `0xFF`) to a `bool` all non-zero values are converted to true and zero values are converted to false.

Comment: Just to be clear, it is the cast from char* to bool* that is causing the undefined behaviour. Nothing to do with the logical negate operator.

Comment: @qbert220: No, you can cast pointer values without causing UB. The standard specifies that if you cast back to the original type then you must get back the original value (the c-style cast will act the same as a `reinterpret_cast` in this case) so the pointer conversion itself cannot cause UB, although it is 'dangerous' or 'unsafe'. It's the act of using the result of the pointer cast which is UB because it it's unspecified what the value of the cast is. Intuitively it can't actually be pointing at an object of the correct type.

Comment: @qbert220: I admit, there is an argument that the unary `*` operator itself causes UB, but there are strong arguments that just forming an _lvalue_ to an invalid object doesn't have to cause UB. E.g., using `&array[size]` to form a pointer to one beyond the end of the array is often argued to be valid because the object `&array[size]` isn't actually "used". Either way, the pointer cast definitely doesn't cause UB but `!` definitely does (because it reads the value of the invalid object), if `*` hasn't already caused UB.

Comment: Yes - I see what you mean about the cast being OK. So it's the dereference of the pointer that causes the undefined behaviour, not the cast and not the negate itself, right?